# tslint did not expect to have jsx in its trivia. What is trivia?

Tags: typescript, pycharm, jsx, tslint

**What does the word "trivia" mean in this context?**

```
Error: Debug Failure. Did not expect JsxExpression to have an Identifier in its trivia
    at addSyntheticNodes (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:110825:30)
    at createChildren (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:110814:9)
    at NodeObject.getChildren (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:110758:56)
    at iterate (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:26)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterate (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterate (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterate (/home/jmunsch/PycharmProjects/pm/node_modules/tsutils/util/util.js:368:50)
```

I get the vague sense it means something like rules, or grammar, but it doesn't seem to quite fit.

I'm using PyCharm, and the error appears every once in a while as I edit some div tags in a tsx file, mostly while i'm mid flight in editing.

---

**related:**

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25487
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TypeScript codebase , "trivia" refers to comments.

Comment: just found this, thanks for the extra context, was having a rough time searching: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview#trivia